# payment gateway for mobile apps

Tags: mobile, payment-gateway

Can you let me know on the best ones for the U.S please? Will be looking for all popular mobile SDKs iPhone, blackberry, android, j2me and windows mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- PayPal
- http://www.cybersource.com/